# trying to search a string with over a large amount of files

Tags: bash, grep

I'm trying to find a string in huge amount of files with

```
grep -rH --include='*.php' "a_string"
```

I need to look only in `*.php` files. Still, it looks like it tries to look over all files, what is wrong with command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your command works in my shell. Personally I do it like that:

```
find -L . -name \*.php | xargs grep --color=auto "a_string"
```

Comment: Or even `find ... -exec grep "a_string" {} +`

Answer (score 0):

you `grep` your string through file globbing

```
grep -R "string" *.php
```

Comment: Wouldn't it include php files in the current directory only ?

Answer (score 0):

what I usually do is:

```
grep "foo" **/*.php
```

you can add `-i` etc. also `-E -P -o`... depends on the pattern and what kind of output do you want.

Answer (score 0):

seems `--include='*.php'` option makes the trouble.

```
grep -rH "a_string" *.php
```